# Display a label in system tray

Tags: vb6

How do I display a label in the system tray ? I need to read the xl file created by my bandwidth meter and always display the MBs used in the system tray.Also is it possible to create a form that is semi transparent, It should be visible over any open windows, not hidden behind ?

Comment: You asked two unrelated questions in a single question. You should ask 2 separate questions. Also, are you really using VB6? Or VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, Windows is set up to draw icons in the system tray, not text. You could create a bitmap, draw text to the bitmap, then show that bitmap icon in the system tray.

Comment: I got the solution to my question of placing a label in the system tray.I use the print command of the picturebox to print numbers to it then I convert it to icon and set it to the icon of the form then use Shell_NotifyIcon method to display the icon in the system tray.

Comment: Glad you got it working like I suggested. Don't forget to accept the answer, thanks!